# How to disable (not remove) toolbar button in leaflet-draw

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

The documentation for leaflet draw provides a way to [remove a toolbar](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-toolbar) but I do not want the toolbar to be removed but rather just be a disabled button.  Is there a known way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I used JS and CSS to toggle a "greyed-out" disabled state for the "add marker" button:

JS:

```js
function toggleMarkerButton(state) {
    // toggle button dimming and clickability
    var button = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-draw-draw-marker")[0];
    if (state) {
        // enable button
        button.onClick = null;
        button.className = "leaflet-draw-draw-marker leaflet-draw-toolbar-button-enabled";
    } else {
        // disable button
        button.onClick = "preventEventDefault(); return false";
        button.className = "leaflet-draw-draw-marker draw-control-disabled";
    }
}
```

CSS:

```css
.draw-control-disabled {
    filter: contrast(22%) brightness(157%);
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Then I used `toggleMarkerButton(false);` to disable the button, and `toggleMarkerButton(true);` to enable it again.